# Intercept all mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to intercept all mouse events (especially clicks) on a web page.

My first instinct was `$('body').click(....)`

But that's not capturing the event if any other Handler is attached for a particular event.

To put the question in context: I'm writing a "statistics" module for my web app. We want to keep track of all user interactions on the pages to adapt. If we see they don't use a functionality we will add a tooltip for example.

I have following frameworks :

jQuery, Knockout and a little Framework "home made"

What I want is a function which is called on each click with mouse position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this (without jQuery):

```
    var eventCount = 0;
    var eventProperty = [];

    var TrackMouse = function (mouseEvent) {
        eventProperty[eventCount++] = {
            id: mouseEvent.toElement.id,
            type: 'mouse',
            ts: Date.now(),
            x: mouseEvent.x,
            y: mouseEvent.y
        };

        console.log("Element id: " + eventProperty[eventCount - 1].id + ", X: " + mouseEvent.x + ", Y: " + mouseEvent.y + "\n");
    };

    document.addEventListener('click', TrackMouse);
```

Comment: Are you sure this event will fire even if there is a custom event on, let say, textbox ?

Comment: Worked perfectlly with little modification. (No array eventProperty and no more counter eventCount++] ) How can I upvote you ?

Comment: Sorry, realized I forgot to declare eventProperty. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theoutlander/UP7yY/

Comment: No worries, worked prefectlly for me ! Thatnk youa lot :) c# i'm your guy, but JS and css..... Not me

Comment: document.addEventListener('click', TrackMouse, **true**); Use the boolean third parameter for event capturing instead of bubbling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing